# HtmlRenderer doesn't render background image from css

Tags: c#, html, css, .net, html-rendering

I use [HtmlRenderer](https://htmlrenderer.codeplex.com/) to generate jpg images from html markup. However it doesn't apply background image from css:

```
<div style="background:url(https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTbNHtYU6bKKmxkJXlqDr7y7afZyZtw-WwDg6DoUNCb9nElkplEuw); width: 440px; height: 361px">
   Some content here.
</div>
```

Here is the C# code:

```
String ecardHtml = File.ReadAllText("testWithGoodImage.html");
using (Image img = HtmlRender.RenderToImageGdiPlus(ecardHtml, maxWidth: 440, textRenderingHint: TextRenderingHint.AntiAliasGridFit))
{
    img.Save("result.jpg");
}
```

Debugging shows that the image is not even requested, so I suspect it's not supported. However `<img>` elements do work well.

So the question is how to make it work.

I know that I can render html on image in HtmlRenderer, but I want to have all markup only in html code.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32376/A-Professional-HTML-Renderer-You-Will-Use ,not sure but it says only color as background is supported!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML renderer supports background Image CSS, if you really want 
to do it in HTML then something like this will do the job :

```
<div style="width: 440px; height: 361px;position:relative">
    <div style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;z-index:8888"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTbNHtYU6bKKmxkJXlqDr7y7afZyZtw-WwDg6DoUNCb9nElkplEuw"/></div>
    <div style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;z-index:9999">Some content here.</div>       
</div>
```

or simply add  background-image not just background

```
<div style="background-image:url(https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTbNHtYU6bKKmxkJXlqDr7y7afZyZtw-WwDg6DoUNCb9nElkplEuw); width: 440px; height: 361px">
   Some content here.
</div>
```

Comment: is it necessary to to add style attribute? what if we are using css file?